# Binding XML data to WPF treeview Control

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have spend a lot of time trying to figure out how to bind data in my XML file to the TreeView control but I do not know where to start. I even tried going through [Two-way binding of Xml data to the WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188001/two-way-binding-of-xml-data-to-the-wpf-treeview) and Josh Smith's code sample on codeproject, but still can't understand how to begin!!!

I have XML in in a file "C:\SPDependencies.xml" (I can change the format if required)!!!:

```
  <node type="SPDependencies" Name="SPDependencies">
        <node type="StoredProc" Name="SP1">
                <node type="OperationType" Name="Type1">
                        <node type="TableName" Name="Table1"/>
                        <node type="TableName" Name="Table2"/>
                </node>
                <node type="OperationType" Name="Type2">
                         <node type="TableName" Name="Table1"/>
                        <node type="TableName" Name="Table2"/>
                </node>
                 .....
        </node>
        <node type="StoredProc" Name="SP2">
              <node type="OperationType" Name="Type1">
              ...
              ...
        </node>
</node>
```

I need to display this in the Treeview control in the following format:

```
<SP1>
   <Type1>
      <Table1>
      <Table2>
      <Table3>
   <Type2>
      <Table1>
      <Table2>
      <Table3>
<SP2>
    <Type1>
........
```

Thanks,
Abhi.

Answer (score 5):

Given the following xml file:

```
<node type="SPDependencies" Name="SPDependencies">
  <node type="StoredProc" Name="SP1">
    <node type="OperationType" Name="Type1">
      <node type="TableName" Name="Table1"/>
    </node>
    <node type="OperationType" Name="Type2">
      <node type="TableName" Name="Table1"/>
    </node>
  </node>
  <node type="StoredProc" Name="SP2">
    <node type="OperationType" Name="Type1">
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="Tree.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tree"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding XPath="node" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=XmlData}">
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public XmlDataProvider XmlData { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        XmlData = new XmlDataProvider();
        XmlData.Source = new Uri(@"C:\input.xml");
        XmlData.XPath = "node";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: tree view output]

If you only want to show the nodes **below** the root, simply change the XPath to:

```
XmlData.XPath = "/node/node";
```

Answer (score 3):

Heres the tree:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="node"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=node}">
        <TextBox Width="Auto"
                 Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <XmlDataProvider
        x:Key="xmlDataProvider"
        XPath="node" Source="C:\Data.XML">
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Save</Button>
            <TreeView
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto"
                Name="treeview"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDataProvider}, XPath=.}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've added a simple button to save changes. So for your Button_Click method in code behind:

```
XmlDataProvider dataProvider = this.FindResource("xmlDataProvider") as XmlDataProvider;
dataProvider.Document.Save(dataProvider.Source.LocalPath);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx) for an article about data binding and WPF.

Comment: I'm interested in this topic, as well.  Is there something missing in your answer?  I can't get any data to display...
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question and post your code so we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to do this without stepping on `TreeView.DataContext`. Binding is easy. Codebehind is nearly as easy, but with one little gotcha.

You get nothing if you bind or assign `XmlDataProvider` to `ItemsSource`. It's not an `IEnumerable` (though it is `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and there's no implicit conversion. What you want is `XmlDataProvider.Data`, which is declared as `Object`, but I'm seeing a runtime type of `XmlDataCollection` (which inherits from `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<XmlNode>`).

## MVVM

Binding `Data` is easy. I don't know if it's pure MVVM to put `XmlDataProvider` in your viewmodel, maybe not.

Viewmodel:

```
public XmlDataProvider ViewModelXMLDataProp { ... }
```

XAML

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelXMLDataProp.Data}"
    ...
    />
```

Done -- that is, unless you need to use the `XPath` property of the `Binding`. If you do, you have to use the `DataContext` kludge. You can't set both `Path` and `XPath` on the same binding.

The XPath property of the `XmlDataProvider` does the same thing. If you can work with that, you're good.

You'd think `Binding.Source` would work, because that works when your `XmlDataProvider` is a static resource. When `Binding.Source` is a `DataSourceProvider` and `Path` is unspecified, `Path` defaults to `Data`:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyXmlDataProviderResource}}"
    ...
    />
```

...but that works because you're giving it a static resource. The following actually binds to the string `"ViewModelXMLDataProp"` rather than looking to the `DataContext` for a property by that name. That's no good.

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ViewModelXMLDataProp}"
    ...
    />
```

Maybe you could write a `MarkupExtension` that'd make that work, but there's no need.

## Codebehind

You should learn and use MVVM, but things happen for a lot of reasons and you didn't come here for a sermon.

Codebehind is a little trickier. `TreeView.ItemsSource` requires nothing more than that the object you give it must implement `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, so cast `provider.Data` to `System.Collections.IEnumerable` and don't worry about what the exact runtime type is.

Now here's the gotcha: `XmlDataProvider.Data` is populated asynchronously.

```
protected void LoadXML(String path)
{
    var provider = 
        new XmlDataProvider()
        {
            Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute),
            XPath = "./*"
        };

    //  FAIL: provider.Data is still null
    treeView.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)provider.Data;
}
```

I found this to be an issue even when I create an `XmlDocument`, call `XmlDocument.Load()`, and assign the document to `XmlDataProvider.Document`. A `Binding` will still be hanging around when the `Data` property finally gets set, and it'll update `ItemsSource` then. But an assignment to `ItemsSource` in your code behind file does no such thing.

Contrary to ubiquitous folk belief at Stack Overflow, in the following code there is no binding happening, and in no sense has anything been bound:

```
//  NOT A BINDING
treeView.ItemsSource = someRandomCollectionOfStuff;
```

If nobody's creating an instance of `System.Windows.Data.Binding` or `x:Bind`, it's not a binding. This distinction matters: "Use the current value of `x`" is not the same concept as "indefinitely update with future values of `y.x` every time `y` raises `PropertyChanged`".

You could programmatically create a `Binding` or even handle `PropertyChanged`, but they went ahead and gave you a much simpler option. Just handle the `XmlDataProvider.DataChanged` event.

```
protected void LoadXML(String path)
{
    var provider = 
        new XmlDataProvider()
        {
            Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute),
            XPath = "./*"
        };

    provider.DataChanged += (s,e) 
        => treeView.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)provider.Data;
}
```

And that does it. You could even keep that provider around, load new XML in it, and have the `DataChanged` event keep the treeview current. Seems like a waste of effort though.