# How to bind XmlDataProvider.Source to MVVM property

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, binding, xmldataprovider

I've got a treeview bound to an `XmlDataProvider` following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188001/two-way-binding-of-xml-data-to-the-wpf-treeview). The app I am working on is following the MVVM pattern and the Xml is from a file that the user will open.

When I try to bind the Source property of the `XmlDataProvider` like so

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="{Binding Path=XmlFilePath}"/>
```

I get a "Binding can only be applied to a DependencyProperty of a Dependency object." or somesuch.

So short of cobbling the binding together procedurally is there a way to declaratively bind the `XmlDataProvider` `Source`? If I try to forgo the data provider and bind the tree directly to an `XmlNode` property I get an error about using XPath binding only with Xml objects; which makes absolutely no sense to me but I'm sure it's trying to tell me something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears to be: you can't.

I was able to solve my underlying problem (binding a treeview to an Xml document) by removing the `XmlDataProvider` from the equation and binding the TreeView directly to a ViewModel property that returns an XmlNode.

What had been tripping me up was that I took the binding code that pointed at the `XmlDataProvider` and pointed it at my property, leaving the XPath argument in place.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectDocument XPath=.}">
```

This would result in a runtime error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 44 : BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.; XPath='.'`

Which was not the most helpful. What it was really trying to say is that you can't bind to an `XmlNode` property AND provide an `XPath` argument in the binding (because it's the XmlDataProvider that knows what to do with that??).

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectDocument}">
```

Comment: Found this many years later while searching for a similar predicament.  If you're doing XPath searches off of a TreeView (long story), you can also bind ItemsSource to an XmlNodeList (and use child::nodes() if no XPath is specified).  That worked great for both single and multi-node returns.  I know it's been 7 years since this post, but hey, information is information.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

actually that was rather tough problem for me, cause I needed the app to load treeview from temp file, and assuming application can have different locations, I can't set strict link in the XmlDataProvider Source property;

### Add source as resource to the project

the solution I found is adding temp file (markup is created via XAML, see below) to the project with build action set to `Content` thus, application **reloads** it every time you call `InitializeComponent()` on the object containing `XmlDataProvider` and my treeview updates.

```
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dshPreview" 
                     Source="~tmpConstruct.xml" 
                     XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource argNms}"   
                     IsAsynchronous="true"/>
```

TreeView is bound like this:

```
  <TreeView  x:Name="PreviewTree" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dshPreview},
             XPath=/mns:engine/mns:ws}"
              />
```

Maybe this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find how to bind the source straight away, but you can change the XmlDataProvider source in the code behind as following:

```
var xdp = (XmlDataProvider)this.Resources["key-of-your-XmlDataProvider-in-resources"];
xdp.Source = new Uri("http://url-of-your-xml");
```

You can use that combined with an event handler to bind.

Comment: the "key-of-your-XmlDataProvider-in-resources" is set using the x:Key attributes once the XmlDataProvider put in control resources.