# Binding against the XmlDataProvider fails?

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, treeview, xmldataprovider

I have some Problems with Binding of a XmlDataProvider to the WPF TreeView.

The TreeView is XAML-Defined like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedSystemVersionHistory}"/>
```

and I have a HierarchicalDataTemplate in the Parent Grid Resource of the TreeView for the Nodes in the XML File:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Documentation" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@SoftwarePackage}"/>
</HierarchiclaDataTemplate>
```

My ViewModel has this Property:

```
public XmlDataProvider SelectedSystemVersionHistory
{
  get
  {
    String file = GetHistoryFile(); //returns full Filepath
    return new XmlDataProvider()
    {
      source = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute),
      XPath= "History"
    };
  }
}
```

And the Xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="utf-8">
  <History>
    <Documentation SoftwarePackage="SoftwarePackageName">
      <Entry>...</Entry>
    </Documentation>
  </History>
```

The Problem is the TreeView doesn't show anything, so what is wrong?
I'm working on this for days now... :o(
thank u for your help.

Comment: Always:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png  Also, no need prefix your title with tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't bind the Document and Source properties of the XmlDataProvider directly, they aren't DependencyProperties.
See also [How to bind XmlDataProvider.Source to MVVM property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866942/how-to-bind-xmldataprovider-source-to-mvvm-property)

What you can do is assign the Treeview's DataContext to the XMLDataProvider:

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding SelectedSystemVersionHistory}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Documentation}"/>
```