# Is there a Hierarchical interface supplied by Microsoft .NET framework?

Tags: .net, interface, hierarchical-data

I want to implement a control with a specifiable DataSource property and it would be great if I could inherit and the type of the DataSource implements some sort of Hierarchical interface with properties and methods ensured.

Does .NET supply such an interface? Googling revealed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188001/two-way-binding-of-xml-data-to-the-wpf-treeview).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are after the [IBindingList interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx).